# Python script or excel formula to compute values in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file with the below format and I need to compute the 'Output' field.

```
Group        Value      Output
1             75          85
1             22         107
1             33         140      
2             20          30
2             32          62
2             10          72
```

I have 2 columns 'Group' and 'Value'. Based on these 2 columns, I need the output column to be calculated. The first value of the 'Output' column in a group will be 10 + 'Value' of that row. And every subsequent row in that group is the sum of the previous 'Output' and 'Value'.
My current approach is to do it manually for each group but I would like to simplify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `cumsum` and just add `10`:

```
df['Output2'] = df.groupby('Group')['Value'].cumsum() + 10
df
```

Output2 column matches your desired output:

```
Out[1]: 
   Group  Value  Output  Output2
0      1     75      85       85
1      1     22     107      107
2      1     33     140      140
3      2     20      30       30
4      2     32      62       62
5      2     10      72       72
```

Full working code if you are a beginner:

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'Your Filepath'
df = pd.read_excel(file)
df['Output'] = df.groupby('Group')['Value'].cumsum() + 10
df.to_excel(file, index=False)
```